# CodeIgniter giving error of unexpeted "endif"

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I setup this if condition for validation, but I'm getting

> syntax error, unexpected endif

my code:

```
<?php if($this->session->flashdata('errors')); ?>
    <?= $this->session->flashdata('errors'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Below is the screen shot of this error

[image]

Comment: Have you read the documentation page about the [alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the if/endif version of the syntax, you want to end the `if` with a colon, not a semi:

```
if($this->session->flashdata('errors')):
    $this->session->flashdata('errors');
endif;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `:` after `if` statement instead of `;`

Change your code to:

```
<?php if($this->session->flashdata('errors')): ?>
    <?= $this->session->flashdata('errors'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: @Caster  any reason for refuse answer which you already have accepted?

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use `;` in `if` statment

```
<?php 
if($this->session->flashdata('errors')) {
    $this->session->flashdata('errors');
} 

//or

if($this->session->flashdata('errors')): 
    $this->session->flashdata('errors'); 
endif; 

//or

if($this->session->flashdata('errors'))
    $this->session->flashdata('errors');
?>
```